# Trigger SharePoint 2013 workflow from JavaScript with different user credentials

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2013

it is possible to start SharePoint (2013) Workflows with JavaScript Client Object Model, and many code examples are available. 
example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn481315.aspx and
http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/08/start-sharepoint-2013-workflows-with.html 
But I have an requirement to use impersonation (initiate the workflow from the default user created for workflows).
So functionality will be any user can execute the JavaScript function but workflow will be triggered from the workflow account i provide. 
Is it possible ? any source or article to refer ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, I don't think there is a possibility to impersonate the account in JSOM. It always operates on the current user context.